# R Plotly: can't make add_markers() function to match positions of boxplot "boxes"

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot, summary

I've been working with R-markdown to generate HTML reports. However, as datasets are huge, building boxplots with the complete data takes too much time, what makes it unfeasible. So I decided pre-calculating summary data and build boxplots from quartiles, mean, median and outlier data using PLOTLY in R. However, I'm struggling when trying to place outliers in the correct x-axis positions for each group of boxplots.

Below, I provide some example code

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

# use summary data for plotly boxplots

# Simulate data.
n <- 10e5
dt <- data.table(trait=rnorm(n),
                 year=sample(2016:2019, n, replace=TRUE),
                 line=factor(sample(letters[1:3], n, replace=TRUE)))

# calculate summary data (summary + outliers) separately
stats <- dt[, boxplot.stats(trait)[1], by=.(year, line)]
out <- dt[, boxplot.stats(trait)[4], keyby=.(year, line)]

# create and plot the BOXPLOT
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data=stats, x=~year, y=~stats, color=~line, type="box") %>%
  layout(boxmode="group") %>%
  add_markers(data=out, x=~year, y=~out, color=~line) %>%
  config(displayModeBar=FALSE, showTips=FALSE)
```

The result is a boxplot by groups with outliers being placed on the same x-axis position for each year, but not sub-dividing for each line-group.

Does anyone have any idea how to make add_markers() place those pre-calculated outlier points in the correct positions in the boxplot???

Comment: Apart from the outliers, the boxes themselves are not right in the code above. You are essentially plotting the box plot of the statistics. The statistics are not generating the box plot.

Comment: @Sada93 As I mentioned, this boxplot is intended to be built from the statistics and not the complete dataset itself. Boxplots are correct and on point, my problem is when trying to align outlier values to their respective group. Currently, they are placed in a straight line.